# How can I approve an XMPP subscription request 'later' in Smack ("Add later" functionality)?

Tags: xmpp, smack

Let us suppose that Alice sends a subscription request to Bob using the next code.

```
public bool AddBuddy(string jid) {
    var roster = conn.Roster;

    // 2` param is nickname
    roster.CreateEntry(jid, null, null);
    roster.SetSubscriptionMode(Roster.SubscriptionMode.Manual);

    Presence subscribe = new Presence(Presence.Type.Subscribe);
    subscribe.To = jid;
    conn.SendPacket(subscribe);
}
```

When Bob has logged, it receives a popup where tell you if you want to added or not in the next method.

```
public void ProcessPacket (Packet p0)
{
        Presence presence = p0.JavaCast<Presence> ();
        var a = presence;
}
```

But I need to implement a "Add Later" functionality. I have no idea how to save the messages in the server and also how to receive all of them

Answer (score 1):

You can delay the subscription as long as you want, there is no need to save the subscriptions packets on the server. And in order to query the deferred subscriptions requests, simply query the roster for subscriptions not in mode `both`.

One remark regarding your code: [`Roster.createEntry(String, String, String[]`](http://fisheye.igniterealtime.org/browse/smack/trunk/source/org/jivesoftware/smack/Roster.java?r=12087#to288) will automatically send the presence packat. No need to send it again.

Comment: Flow, Could you please elaborate how I can put the code while sending a subscription request for the same issue.I am new to it and didn't understand what you explained.Please help me to find out the meaning of line : **"simply query the roster for subscriptions not in mode both."**

Answer (score 0):

No need to save anything on the server as it maintains pending subscribe requests automatically, ie. whenever you login to the server at a later time, the subscribe request will be pushed to you again (if it wasn't dealt with before). Therefore, just save the subscribe request locally in your application in a list or something whenever you receive it from the server, and show that local request list to the user as a "Friend request page" for the user to accept/reject. If your application's lifecycle restarts, it will be receiving all pending subsribe presences again from the server (or whenever it re-logins). Let me know if this works for you.